# How to improve performance of SUM aggregate function in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We are working on a SQL query to improve performance. Query is

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.fDebitAmount),
    SUM(p.fCreditAmount)
FROM 
    tSCCompany c
LEFT JOIN  
    tGLPostSummary   p ON (c.fCompanyID = p.fCompanyID AND p.fAccount = c.fEnterpriseAccount AND p.fPostDate <= '2014-08-19 21:51:56')  
INNER JOIN 
    tSCLedgerAccount l ON (c.fCompanyID = l.fCompanyID AND c.fEnterpriseAccount = l.fAccount)  
WHERE 
    c.fEnterpriseID = '4FD5CB57-C04E-11D2-8C59-00A02492E6F3'  
    AND c.fCompanyID = 'A1F266BA-FC99-11D2-B221-0008C7B1BE09' 
    AND c.fEnterpriseAccount = '202'
    AND c.fCurrencyID = '1'
```

Above query is taking **6 sec.**  to execute

Please reference the attached image for further explanation.

[image]

Is there any way to reduce these time to improve performance of query?

We try use `SUM` function with over but it is giving exception like order by syntax error.

We are using index properly on our database.Actually database exist on client side and it is Handel my client. So all the task related to database schema or structure is done by client. We have no permission to update database design. Please suggest me on query level how can we improve performance.

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the fields in your join statements and where clause?

Comment: what does the query plan show? are the statistics up to date? are indexes used as expected?

Comment: Please suggest me on query level how can we improve performance

Comment: ¿What datatype is fPostDate from tGLPostSummary?

Comment: What is the join to tSCLedgerAccount 'l' for? I see where clauses on the c columns that filters on the fields used in the join, but they can all be referenced in the 'c' table. Should be able to remove that join entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.fDebitAmount),
    SUM(p.fCreditAmount)
FROM tSCCompany c
INNER JOIN tSCLedgerAccount l ON (c.fCompanyID = l.fCompanyID AND c.fEnterpriseAccount =l.fAccount)  
LEFT JOIN  
    tGLPostSummary   p ON (c.fCompanyID = p.fCompanyID AND p.fAccount =      c.fEnterpriseAccount )  
WHERE 
c.fEnterpriseID = '4FD5CB57-C04E-11D2-8C59-00A02492E6F3'  
AND c.fCompanyID = 'A1F266BA-FC99-11D2-B221-0008C7B1BE09' 
AND c.fEnterpriseAccount = '202'
AND c.fCurrencyID = '1' AND Convert(char,p.fPostDate,109) <= Convert(Char,Convert(datetime,'2014-08-19 21:51:56'),109)
```